# Stretching preview in the custom camera android

Tags: android, api

I'm using code inside this book "Pro Android Media
Developing Graphics, Music, Video, and Rich Media Apps for Smartphones and Tablets", and i have problem with preview of camera

and I used camera API in my app

I face some problem :

1) The display appear in the case of stretched, in the case of the lowest link shows the difference between the camera original phone and custom camera

[here video for my problem i face](http://b.top4top.net/m_23418no1.mov)

[OR here video for my problem i face](https://ufile.io/704e4)

Answer (score 0):

The following code which I found somewhere helped me.

You essentially have to scale the preview in accordance with your screen size and for that this method should suffice,

```
private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio=(double)h / w;

    if (sizes == null) return null;

    Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    int targetHeight = h;

    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
        }
    }

    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
    }
    return optimalSize;
}
```

Now you are to Override the onMeasure in your preview Activity which I presume is extending the SurfaceView like this,

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
    final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

    if(mCamera != null) {
        List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }
    }
}
```

and finally start the preview with the tuned PreviewSize calculated in onMeasure like this,

```
// start preview with new settings
    try {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);

        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        isSafeToTakePicture = true;

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```